# bash script in cygwin is misreading an environment variable

Tags: bash, cygwin

I'm trying to run a bash shell script in Cygwin on a Windows PC.  I have a JAVA_HOME environment variable set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171.  When I run the program it generates the error "Error: Could not find or load main class Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171.bin:C:\Program". The program appears to be reading "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\bin\" as "Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171.bin:C:\Program". How can I fix this?

Comment: If you're using the Java coming with cygwin, specify the cygwin path instead of the Windows path: `/cygdrive/c/...`

Comment: there is no Java in cygwin. the Java machine is a windows program

Comment: What @choroba says is right. You are using windows, but accessing it in the cygwin environment. The path formats are different, they are unix like in cygwin.

Comment: This also sounds like you have an un-quoted env Var, but hard to say where it is. If you have a script, then  be sure to use `JAVA_PATH="C:\Program Files\...."` . And you may need unix format for the path, so then do `JAVA_PATH="/c/Program Files/..."`. Good luck.